# Creating an async method which throws an exception after a specified amount of time unless a certain condition is met outside of that function

Tags: ruby, multithreading, asynchronous, timeout

I am currently working on a Ruby script which is supposed to perform different tasks on a pretty long list of hosts. I am using the net-ssh gem for connectivity with those hosts. The thing is, there seem to exist some conditions under which net-ssh times out without throwing an exception. As of know, the script was only once able to finish a run. Most of the time, the scripts just hangs at some point without ever throwing an exception or doing anything.

I thought about running all tasks that may timeout in different threads, passing them a pointer to some variable they can change when the tasks finished successfully, and then check that variable for a given amount of time. If the task has not finished by then, throw an exception in the main thread that I can catch somewhere.

This is the first time I am writing something in Ruby. To give a clear demonstration of what I want to accomplish, this is what I'd do in C++:

```cpp
    void perform_long_running_task(bool* finished);
    void start_task_and_throw_on_timeout(int secs, std::function<void(bool*)> func);
    int seconds_to_wait {5};
    int seconds_task_takes{6};


    int main() {
        start_task_and_throw_on_timeout(seconds_to_wait, &perform_long_running_task);
        // do other stuff
        return 0;
    }

    void perform_long_running_task(bool* finished){
        // Do something that may possible timeout..
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(seconds_task_takes));

        // Finished..
        *finished = true;
    }

    void start_task_and_throw_on_timeout(int secs, std::function<void(bool*)> func){
        bool finished {false};
        std::thread task(func, &finished);

        while (secs > 0){
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            secs--;
            if (finished){
                task.join();
                return;
            }
        }

        throw std::exception();
    }
```

Here, when 'seconds_task_takes' is bigger than 'seconds_to_wait', an exception is thrown in the main thread. If the task finishes in time, everything goes on smoothly.

However, I need to write my piece of software in a dynamic scripting language that can run anywhere and needs not to be compiled. I would be super glad for any advice about how I could write something like the code above in Ruby.

Thanks alot in advance :)

edit: in the example ,I added a std::function parameter to start_task_and_throw_timeout so it's reusable for all similar functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think module `timeout` has everything you need to do. It allows you to run the block for a while and raise an exception if it was not fast enough.

Here is a code example:

```rb
require "timeout"

def run(name)
  puts "Running the job #{name}"
  sleep(10)
end


begin
  Timeout::timeout(5) { run("hard") }
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts "Failed!"
end
```

You can play with it here: https://repl.it/repls/CraftyUnluckyCore. The documentation for the module lives here: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html. Notice that you can customize not only the timeout, but also error class and message, so different jobs may have different kinds of errors.

Comment: Note that `Timeout` can be very dangerous with many cases of undefined behavior. I would not rely on it in production unless you dig into its internals and really understand how it's dealing with thread interruption. Ideally, your long running tasks use libraries that have already meticulously tested that for you (e.g. `Net::HTTP`'s `read_timeout` option); you should much prefer using those native options instead. Otherwise, you need to dig into the `timeout` internals to make sure your code actually runs as intended. Cf: https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-ruby-dont-use-timeout-77d9d4e5a001

Comment: > However, I need to write my piece of software in a dynamic scripting language that can run anywhere and needs not to be compiled. I would be super glad for any advice about how I could write something like the code above in Ruby. --- If you have a choice of tools, I would also point out that Ruby does single threaded scripting very well, but concurrency has always been a weakness for it. I'd point you to NodeJS if you can use single threaded async behavior instead. If you're looking for something that's similar to Ruby syntax-wise, Elixir works interactively, though still needs compilation.